# Initial image of onmouseover/out won't load, but will work fine after mousing over the first time

Tags: html, onmouseover, onmouseout

On a website I am building, the onmouseover/out feature is working, however the initial image that is meant to be there won't load and will instead show a blank image link like it's trying to find it. When I do mouseover, the pictures load and are fine from then on.

I've tried changing the image it tries to load initially (which is definitely in the right place as it's one of the onmouseover/out pictures that functions correctly), but it still won't load.

```
<header class="masthead text-center">
      <div style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden">
        <img class='img-responsive center-block' src="/images/people/MinION" width="500"> 
          <a href="https://team-schwessinger.github.io/Team_B_S/" />
      </div>
      <img class='img-reponsive center-block' img src="images/people/MionION.png" width="500" alt="Leaf" onmouseover="this.src='images/people/Leaf.jpg';" width="500" onmouseout="this.src='images/people/MinION.jpg';" width="500" /></a>
```

I believe I am having an issue with

```
<img class='img-responsive center-block' src="/images/people/MinION" width="500">
```

which is meant to be there when the website loads, before any mousing occurs. The website recognises it is trying to find a picture, but can't. I am confused about this as it is able to find and use that MinION picture in the actual mouseover function.

Any help in understanding why this is happening is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your syntax as below, I have changed image links for me to work but you can use your relative paths.

```
<header class="masthead text-center">
        <div style="width:1px; height:1px; visibility:hidden; overflow:hidden">
          <a href="https://team-schwessinger.github.io/Team_B_S/" />
             <img class='img-responsive center-block' 
             src="https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/googles-new-logo- 
             5078286822539264-2-hp.gif" width="500">
         </div>

         <a href="https://team-schwessinger.github.io/Team_B_S/">
            <img class='img-reponsive center-block' img 
             src="https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/googles-new-logo- 
             5078286822539264-2-hp.gif" width="500" alt="Leaf" 
             onmouseover="this.src='http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/st- 
             patricks-day-2016-4834639321497600-hp2x.gif';" width="500"            
          onmouseout="this.src='https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264-2-hp.gif';" width="500" />
         </a>
```

[refer to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/datt265/k9ab1ntm/15/)